# tensorflow export model and run it on Android failed

Tags: android, tensorflow

I train an model using tensorflow on gpu server(K40), and then I export the model using session bundle, and I could run the exported model on PC computer. But when I use it on android, an error occurs:

tensorflow_jni.cc:184 Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (tensorflow::serving::GetDefaultSignature(bundle.meta_graph_def, &signature)) (OK vs. Failed precondition: Expected signature Any type_url for: tensorflow.serving.Signatures. Got: type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.contrib.Signatures.)

We are frustrated about this error, I have no idea what is wrong during the process?

Comment: @Yuan Yu may be able to answer this question

Comment: A longer stack trace would help here. It looks like the server in android is expecting a different proto as the signature thing. Are you building both servers from the same version?